# How to append a dot at the beginning of a string in array-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
arr= ["abd","test","testss"];
```

I want to add dot in front of all the strings like:

```
arr= [".abd",".test",".testss"];
```

this failed:

```
arr.forEach(function(e){
  e.append(".")
})
```

how can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Concatenating_strings

Comment: FWIW, strings are immutable in JavaScript, i.e. any operation you can do on a string produces a new string value that you have to assign to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.map API, like this -

```js
arr= ["abd","test","testss"];

console.log(arr.map(item => `.${item}` ))
```

Comment: `item => \`.${item}\``

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `map()` method on the array type to achieve this:

```js
var arr = ["abd","test","testss"];

// Iterate each string of arr, add a '.' to the start, 
// and return a copy of the updated array
arr = arr.map(function(value) { return '.' + value; })
    
console.log(arr)
```

If you're working with a fairly modern browser, you could also take advantage of modern syntax to achieve the same result via the following:

```js
var arr = ["abd","test","testss"];

// Iterate each string of arr, add a '.' to the start, 
// and return a copy of the updated array
arr = arr.map(value => `.${value}`)
    
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array.map to do this.
Array.map would let you travere the elements and returns an array.
Here is the following snippet

```js
let arr= ["abd","test","testss"];
arr = arr.map(item=> `.${item}`);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use all the parameters provided by `forEach`, which are (1) the value of current element, (2) the index of the current element, (3) the array reference itself. Translated into code that would mean:

```
let arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

arr.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
    array[index] = '.' + value
});

// arr = ['.abc', '.def', '.ghi']
```

I am sure that there is a faster and possibly shorter way to do it, but hey it's something.

Answer (score 1):

This is for backward compatibility, without using transpilation.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = '.' + arr[i];

console.log(arr); // ['.a', '.b', '.c', '.d', '.e']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the strings don't have special chars, you can join and split.

```js
let arr = ["abd", "test", "testss"];
console.log(("." + arr.join('|.')).split('|'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```